# Can the angle between two vectors be negative?

Tags: notation, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics, angle

**Question:**

The angle between two vectors $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{Q}$ is $\alpha$. If $\tan\alpha=-\sqrt{3}$, determine $\alpha$.

**My attempt:**

$$\tan\alpha=-\sqrt{3}$$

$$\alpha=\tan^{-1}(-\sqrt{3})$$

$$\alpha=-60^{\circ}$$

**My book's attempt:**

$$\tan\alpha=-\sqrt{3}$$

$$\tan\alpha=-\tan(60^{\circ})$$

$$\tan\alpha=\tan(180^{\circ}-60^{\circ})$$

$$\tan\alpha=\tan(120^{\circ})$$

$$\alpha=120^{\circ}$$

**Addendum:**

[image]

Interestingly enough, $-60^{\circ}$ and $120^{\circ}$ are describing two different cases. If the answers were $120^{\circ}$ and $-240^{\circ}$, I would've had no problem as they are both describing the same case, unlike here. Here, $-60^{\circ}$ and $120^{\circ}$ are describing two different things and they both can't be correct.

**My question:**

Whose answer is correct, mine or my book's? I know that there's a rule stating that the [angle between two vectors can' be greater than $180^{\circ}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4390688/768162). Is there another rule that states that the angle between two vectors can't be less than $0^{\circ}$?

Comment: What is tangent's period ?

Comment: Usually the angle is defined to be greater than or equal to 0 and less than 180 degrees

Comment: @JackT Not really, negative angles are pretty common in trigonometry. $\sin(x)$ after all is defined on *both* the negative and postive numbers.

Comment: It really depends on your definition of "angle between vectors". While angles in general can be negative, the angle between vectors is typically defined to be in $[0,180^{\circ}]$. You can however also define and oriented angle if the direction of the vectors matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angle Between 2 Vectors Restrictions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468651/angle-between-2-vectors-restrictions). See also [How does this definition of the oriented angle differ from the usual (non reflexive angle) one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689309)

Comment: Then also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space#Angle and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Positive_and_negative_angles

Comment: @Sil Fair enough!

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic You're overcomplicating things. As discussed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4253493/21813) to your previous question (scroll to the end), the angle between two vectors is uniquely and conventionally specified on $[0,180^\circ]$ (as usual, this is not an arbitrary "rule" but a sensible convention, due to the specification's non-ambiguity). Since the given angle's tangent is negative, it can lie only in quadrant 2.